# How to get UNC Paths from <input type="file">

Tags: internet-explorer, file-io, upload

I have an `<input type="file">` used to upload files on my server.

I'm having some problems with IE (11) because `<input type="file">` gets the logical file path (for example E:folder/pictures/). My application stands on a server so it looks for files locally but of course without finding them. I need to obtain the UNC path in order to be able to update files correctly.

How can I translate/change the logical path to the UNC (e.g \\servername\folder\pictures)??

I've been trying to find some solution over the Internet but I couldn't find a good one for me..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution!

The IE security setting 'Include local directory path when uploading files to a server' should be DISABLED!

Very easy one, so tough to get it though!